# Map SQL Query to Business object in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I want to map SQL query to `Business object` using `Nhibernate`. There are lot fields in Employee table, but I am getting three only and want map only those one.

here is my sql query

```
<sql-query  name="findEmployeesInfo">
<return alias="emp" class="Calibr.BusinessDocuments.BOs.Employee, BusinessDocuments"/>
<![CDATA[
  select (emp.Eid) as {emp.Id},(emp.FirstName) as {emp.FirstName},(emp.LastName) as {emp.LastName} from Employee emp
 ]]>
</sql-query>
```

here is I have make constructor to map those columns

```
public Employee(int Id, string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LastName = LastName;            
}
```

**DB Employee table Column Names:** Eid, FirstName,LastName,............

I am getting this exception

> could not execute query
>   [ select (emp.Eid) as Eid1_0_,(emp.FirstName) as FirstName1_0_,(emp.LastName) as LastName1_0_ from Employee emp

**Edit:** if I select all columns, it will work perfect -- `Select * from Employee emp`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would benefit from using NHibernate's [ad-hoc mapping](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/06/30/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A%20LosTechies%20%2528LosTechies%2529) features:

**Named query:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <sql-query name="findEmployeesInfo">
      select emp.Eid as Id, emp.FirstName FirstName, emp.LastName as LastName from Employee emp
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Employee class:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

**Ad-hoc query:**

```
IList<Employee> employees = session
                              .GetNamedQuery("findEmployeesInfo")
                              .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Employee)))
                              .List<Employee>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please read my question again and then reply.

Comment: That's not the solution of my problem. As I am asking different thing and my structure but your reply is entirely different.

Comment: How is my answer entirely different? I'm mapping an SQL result to an Employee object. Can we at least see how you formulate your query?

Comment: And by the way, you need to give us the inner exception, not just the first one.

Comment: Eek, major time zone difference + no "skype" hardware. Do update your post. :)

Comment: I have added my answer, how I have added. Actully your answer is right but my architecture is different. that's I can;t follow your answer. But anyway thanks for your help.