# Execute a custom query in nhibernate and map to a custom domain object

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Hi i have a query like this

```
SELECT Customer.Name, sum([Load].Profit) as Profit FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Load] ON Customer.Id = [Load].CustomerId GROUP BY Customer.Name
```

I need to execute this query in nhibernate and map it to a Custom domain object which i created as like this

```
public class CustomerProfit
    {
        public String Name;
        public Decimal Profit;

    }
```

Is it possible to do so ? and how , or is it possible to execute this custom query in HQL ?

Comment: what do you prefer: a) minimal work with resulttransformer but no changetracking b) mapping as entity with custom sql and more work but change tracking and stuff

Comment: As the requirement i think i prefer a :-)

Comment: See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964147/map-sql-query-to-business-object-in-nhibernate
Maybe helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
public sealed class CustomerProfitQuery : IResultTransformer
{
    public static readonly string Sql = "SELECT Customer.Name, sum([Load].Profit) as Profit FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Load] ON Customer.Id = [Load].CustomerId GROUP BY Customer.Name";
    public static readonly CustomerProfitQuery Transformer = new CustomerProfitQuery();

    // make it singleton
    private CustomerProfitQuery()
    { }

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        return collection;
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        return new CustomerProfit
        {
            Name = (string)tuple[0],
            Profit = (decimal)tuple[1],
        };
    }
}


// usage
var customerprofits = session.CreateSQLQuery(CustomerProfitQuery.Sql)
    .SetResultTransformer(CustomerProfitQuery.Transformer)
    .List<CustomerProfit>()
```